# How do i install windows xp on my partitioned mac hard drive, without a CD?

Tags: windows, macos, windows-xp, mac, multi-boot

The situation is that my Macbook Pro's disk drive doesn't work. It just rejects a lot of CDs or DVDs you put in there. I've partitioned the hard drive using Disk Utility, so now i have 225GB of OS X and 25GB of an empty FAT partition. I have a USB with the contents of the windows xp install disk burned to it. I try and hold down alt when restarting, but my usb doesn't come up as one of the options. What can i do to allow it to boot from my usb, and thus install windows?

Answer (score 0):

Just make an USB installer on a flash drive. Your USB drive needs to be bootable. You could use e.g. [WinToFlash](http://wintoflash.com/home/en/)
Use boot camp tool on OSX to prepare your HDD not manually with disk util.

If you crash into problems booting the installer from USB but you're sure it's a bootable flash drive you have to use [rEFIt](http://refit.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: That looks great, except it's a windows program. Is there a mac alternative? There's also the problem that when i hold down alt, my mac doesn't count the usb as being a boot source. I don't know if this will change anything.

Comment: afaik there is no easy to use tool to build suchs installer with mac. you could install it virtually

Comment: Or you could give Carbon copy cloner a try. It can make bootable copies of osx DVDs to flash

Comment: @Andrew Get a virtualization program, such as VirtualBox (http://virtualbox.org), build a Windows VM with an ISO image of the Windows disc, use that VM to build your USB installer.  You don't even need to activate Windows on the VM, since it's a short-term temporary setup.

Comment: And will that mean it'll come up as a boot source?

Comment: IF your flash drive is bootable the Mac should recognize it.